# Image Upload Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload images to my node.js server through react application. I've used Multer and path npm packages for that. But whenever I upload it shows error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

```
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public/images")));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "/public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json("File uploded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

full error :

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)     
    at Object.join (node:path:429:7)
    at F:\VS\MERN clones\SocialApp\server\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:37:28
    at DiskStorage.filename [as getFilename] (F:\VS\MERN clones\SocialApp\server\index.js:50:5)
    at F:\VS\MERN clones\SocialApp\server\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:34:10
    at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination] (F:\VS\MERN clones\SocialApp\server\index.js:47:5)
    at DiskStorage._handleFile (F:\VS\MERN clones\SocialApp\  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: At your statement `cb(null, req.body.name)`, `req.body.name` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

path you provided is wrong. it should be ./public/images or ../public/images as per the location of the folder.

Comment: While your statement is probably true, the error is not caused by that.
Also, please put more effort into formatting your answer. 
Sentences start with capital letters, quote paths's ....

Comment: The error message is very clear as to the error in question. The "TYPE" reported, is not of the "string" type, as expected by the parameter.